# How do I hold a message from flowing until a dependant service completes

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a message channel through which one endpoint can send a message to the other. Now, whenever a message comes to the channel I want an internal business service be invoked, lets suppose the service counts the number of messages passing through the channel. However, what I don't want is to let the message pass through until the service method returns.

What sort of channel and endpoint configuration can make this happen?

A couple of points to note:

- A periodic poller on the receiving end doesn't fulfil the
  requirement as the poller is neither aware of the arrival of a message
  into the channel, nor it knows when the service method returns
- The service method is not interested in the content of the message.
  It just needs to be invoked (with no args) as soon as a message
  arrives. Neither it returns anything. This is why using a filter
  won't be an ideal solution (where the filter simply carries forward
  any incoming message and invokes the service method in between)

**Edit:** One possible thing that could happen with the service method is it may throw an exception. In such a scenario the message shouldn't be let go and something else needs to be done. But the reason of exception is not related to the message payload as it doesn't do anything with the payload. It just increments a message counter, for example. That is why I mentioned the message itself should not (ideally) be sent to the service method, it just needs to be triggered appropriately and the channel should allow the message to be dispatched to the final endpoint once the service method has successfully returned. (I am just thinking, rather than the service method having the possibility of throwing an exception you may consider returning a boolean value instead; i.e. true if passed and false otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean - you say the service returns no result but you want the message to "pass through". No result in a linear flow means end of flow - there is no result message to flow through.

If you mean you want to call one service with a message and then pass the same message to some other service, then simply make the channel a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`. Subscribe the first service (`order="1"`) - no output channel, and the second service (`order="2"`). When the first service returns, the message will be sent to the second service (you must not add a task-executor, however).

Note that while the message itself is immutable, the payload may not be - that means any changes made by the first service will be seen by the second service.

**EDIT:** That is the default behavior - if the first subscriber throws an exception, the message won't go to the next subscriber (this behavior can be modified by setting `ignore-failures="true"`). The default is for the exception to be thrown and can be handled by an `error-channel` on the inbound endpoint (where the flow starts), or an intermediate error handling gateway.

If you don't want the first service to "see" the message, add a transformer before it - the second subscriber will still get the original message.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I think you are getting closer. Please see my edit in the original question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Answer edited to explain that what you want is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If the service method is not interested in the payload nor returns anything, why not wrapping the service call into a simple filter that always return true?